# Firebase RTDB Security Rules limit overall size of user data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm looking to find a way to limit the amount of data a user can upload to their portion of my firebase database. I mentioned security rules as this would seem to be the easiest and safest way to implement but I'm open to any suggestions.

Lets say for example I have a firebase rtdb structured like the example below and I want to limit the overall amount of data in each 'User' branch. I'm not trying to limit how much they write on any given upload, just overall how much they have stored total. The app itself is a web app with html, js and css.

```
root-
    - User1 //security rule to detect/set a max data limit for all User1 data
          - Data: Some values
          - Data2: Something else
          //and so on
```

I looked for any similar questions but could not find anything relating to this particular need. If anyone has a link to documentation, article or solution I'm happy to do the reading!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules cannot be used to limit size of a node. You can write data through a Cloud function that roughly calculates size of data being added (packages like [`object-sizeof`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof) might be useful) and then stores the size somewhere in the database. You can then later check for the size before updating/adding data to that node.

Comment: Thanks! I setup a function to trigger when any user node is written to in the DB and added the data point within the users node. Now I just check that value is less than a certain amount using the firebase security rules.

Comment: I have a new issue. The validation security rules prevents a 'write' operation if the data value exceeds a certain limit. However, it also prevents a user from deleting data. Is there a way in firebase security to separate a 'write' operation from a 'delete' operation or are they both considered a 'write'?